# Double precision magic in C#

Tags: .net

This is a very simple example to demonstrate floating point imprecision:

```
double a = 0.33;
double b = 0.1;
double c = a + b;

printf("%.90f\n", c);

// output: 0.430000000000000048849813083506887778639793395996093750000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The same code in C# seems to yield the precise value for 'c':

```
double a = 0.33;
double b = 0.1; 
double c = a + b;

Console.WriteLine($"{c:N90}");
  
// output: 0.430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

What's happening on the C#/dotNet side?

Comment: I'll see `0.430000000000000048849813083506887778639793395996093750000000000000000000000000000000000000` value in my end, which is closer to your c++ sample. Also, [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) has 15-17 precision digits

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Float80 vs float64 rounding maybe? What do you get if you try it in debug build?

Comment: Pavel, I copied the result from the Debugger Output window. Do you use the same code as in the post?

Comment: @AttilaKaroly [`Double` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-5.0) says _In addition, the result of arithmetic and assignment operations with `Double` values may differ slightly by platform because of the loss of precision of the `Double` type_ I'm using a .net core 3.1, you haven't mentioned any details in your question, therefore it's hard to tell what's going wrong

Comment: @Pavel, I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10 and VS 2017

Comment: `G17` format specifier gives you a `0.43000000000000005` value in output for .NET 4.7.2, according to [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZXl3vG)

Comment: FYI - LinqPad5 (.Net Framework) gives `0.430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` but LinqPad6 (.Net Core) gives `0.430000000000000048849813083506887778639793395996093750000000000000000000000000000000000000` on the same machine

Comment: @phuzi Do you get those results in both debug and release?

Comment: Try with `F90` formatting instead of `N90`. I think `N90` converts the value to `decimal` which is more precise for decimal values.

Comment: To get the full stored value of `c` (without rounding of last bits) use `c.ToString("R")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used in VS2019

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a = 0.33;
        double b = 0.1;
        double c = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine($"{"Format",-8} {"Value"}");

        Console.WriteLine($"{"G",-8} {c:G}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"R",-8} {c:R}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"F40",-8} {c:F40}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"N40",-8} {c:N40}");            
    }
}
```

with the output

```
Format   Value
G        0.43
R        0.43000000000000005
F40      0.4300000000000000000000000000000000000000
N40      0.4300000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So even if the stored bitvalue corresponds to `0.43000000000000005` the display process rounds of some bits from the end to make the numbers nicer.

```
0.43000000000000005 = 0b11111111011011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000110
0.43000000000000000 = 0b11111111011011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101
```

The difference being the last bit being rounded down. This piece of logic must be buried in the formatting functions for `double` in the framework.

---

Looking into this a bit deeper the following happens outside of the CLR.

The following function in [`Number.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,c50101de0d63cbb7) is called to convert a `double` into a `string`.

[image: Number.cs]

As you can see it is marked `extern` which means it calls an unmanaged function in the underlying C++ library.